# Why am I not able to add to the end of the linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list

I wanted to write some practice code to be able to add to the end of the linked list , but the code below is not adding the elements 5 to 9 to the linked list. It only adds 0 - 4 to the list.

I tweaked the way I was traversing the linked list which fixed the issue , but I still dont understand very clearly why the first piece of code was not printing correctly.

```
SinglyLinkedList<Integer> sg = new SinglyLinkedList<>();
    System.out.println(sg.searchNode(5));
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

      sg.insertAtHead(i);
    }

    for (int i = 5; i < 10; i++) {

      sg.insertAtEnd(i);
    }

    sg.printList();
  }
```

Code that did not work :

```
public void insertAtEnd(T data) {

    if (isEmpty()) {

      insertAtHead(data);
      return;
    }

    Node newNode = new Node();
    newNode.data = data;
    newNode.nextNode = null;

    Node currentNode = headNode;


    while (currentNode != null) {

      currentNode = currentNode.nextNode;
    }

    currentNode = newNode;
    size++;
  }
```

Code that worked :

```
public void insertAtEnd(T data) {

    if (isEmpty()) {

      insertAtHead(data);
      return;
    }

    Node newNode = new Node();
    newNode.data = data;
    newNode.nextNode = null;

    Node currentNode = headNode;

    while (currentNode.nextNode != null) {

      currentNode = currentNode.nextNode;
    }

    currentNode.nextNode = newNode;
    size++;
  }
```

- The output for the correctly working code is `4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> NULL`
- The output for the incorrect code is `4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0 -> NULL`

Answer (score 0):

In the method which doesn't work, you need to change

```java
currentNode = newNode;
```

to

```java
currentNode.nextNode = newNode;
```

The reason for this is that `currentNode` is simply a reference to where you are on the linked list. Changing the value of `currentNode` does not affect the linked list at all. Imagine the linked list as a drawing on a whiteboard. `currentNode` is just an arrow pointing to the currently selected node. By changing the value of `currentNode`, you simply move the arrow to the newly created node, which is not connected to the linked list yet. To add it to the end, you have to draw an arrow from `currentNode` to `newNode`.